# Accessing a list of lists

Tags: python, list, types, scikit-learn, kaggle

I have data in the form of a list of lists. I wanted to do something like `(data[1::100])[3]`, where I access the first 100 elements, and then just the third column of all those elements. In tutorials on Kaggle, I had seen things like `data[1::100,3]`, but Python says:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple.

Is there an easy way to do this? I could just use a loop or something, but this will come up a lot so it would be nice to have some shorthand.

Comment: `1::100,3` is a syntax for NumPy arrays, it won't work with Python lists. Convert `data` to a NumPy array: `data = numpy.array(data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a list of lists, you can do:

```
values = [l[3] for l in data[:100]]
```

to achieve the same thing.